# Trigger an event when callee returns 180 ringing?

Tags: asterisk, amazon-ami

The situation as follows : 
User A Dials User B 
User B returns 180 Ringing

Both of them in the same PBX  (Asterisk 11.5) and registered.

I would like to know if it is possible to trigger an action when User B returns 180 Ringing  (and before the we gets 200 OK)

What I'v tried to do is send the call to a label before the call connects with option "B" of  Dial() command and get the SIP status with:

```
${HASH(SIP_CAUSE,${CDR(dstchannel)})
```

and

```
${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/${CALLEE})}
```

Update:

The problem is the macro launched by Dial()'s "B" option is launched before the invite is sent, so the actions I'v preformed are useless.

I'm aware it's possible to get a state of ringing with AMI (with Newstate event) but in this point I don't to add another complexity for the task.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not posible. Becuase pbx structures of outgoing channels will be no initialized.

You have go with external AMI script or have do complex rewrite of asterisk core.

Comment: Thanks, i'm considering another method of initiating SIP OPTIONS / NOTIFY  to User "B". it should give me a status if the other side "alive"

Comment: Hi, i'v implemented a patch to solve this issue. i'v posted a question to just to validate if the solution is elegant enough:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891874/issue-with-dialing-registered-but-offline-users